# "Say! Wassup!" Please, can anybody explain to me what the word "say" means here?

Tags: etymology

"Say! Wassup!" - Please, can anybody explain to me what the word "say" means here? Is it literally "say" as an action or may it be a kind of "hey+say" in one word? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way you have captured / written it down here, it's an interjection, a word of surprise and greeting. It's certainly possible to be used as a verb (imperative), but Tim that case it would be written *Say "wassup!"*.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84728/what-is-the-origin-of-the-dated-british-expression-i-say - I think 'Say! Wassup!' is a shortened and modernised version of 'I say! Wassup!'

Comment: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/say) gives the pragmatic marker: registering of surprise / attention grabbing usage << EXCLAMATION

_North American 
informal_ 
Used to express surprise or to draw attention to a remark or question.
‘say, did you notice any blood?’ >>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Say!" is a greeting before "what is up". It is essentially expressing a request for the listener to speak to the speaker. It is used very informally in situations, for example, where the speaker just walked into a room and wants to greet someone. The entire phrase is essentially "talk to me.....what is going on?" in a friendly situation.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of *say* here is to gain somebody's attention before speaking or asking a question. Here is what [Wiktionary says](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/say#Etymology_2)

> Adverb[edit]
>   say (not comparable)
>
> (colloquial) Used to gain one's attention before making an inquiry or suggestion
>
> Say, what did you think about the movie?
>
> For example; let us assume.
>
> Pick a color you think they'd like, say, peach.
>
> He was driving pretty fast, say, fifty miles per hour.
>
> Synonyms[edit]
>   (used to gain attention): hey