# Use of "Say ..." to begin sentences, particularly in BrE versus AmE?

Tags: meaning, american-english, british-english, figures-of-speech, dialects

We were looking at this sentence, or actually a line of dialogue:

> They're in the car.
>
> JACK
> Say John! I better concentrate. Would you be able to figure out the AC?

Our colleague Jane who is generally British (she has lived mixed in Britain and Euro countries, but never the US) commented:

> "Ahah it’s probably because I’m from the UK, but I never hear “Say” to start a sentence to get someone’s attention! As in [that example]. Is it an American thing?"

What is everyone's opinion on this?

Is there any scholarly research on the issue?

(I personally do and have always lived both in the AmE region and BrE region, so I am completely confused on such matters.  For example, right now without googling the answer, I do not know which side uses "boot" versus "trunk" on a car, and so on.)

So in BrE, if the Beatles were talking and George said "Say Ringo. Have you seen ..." would that be unusual, AmE-ish, wrong?

For me it's quite a natural thing to say. Example, you're sitting with your spouse, "Say honey. What would you like for dinner."  But maybe I'm completely mistaken.

Could it just be archaic?  I'm sure I've been in a meeting, for example, where everyone is puzzling over a problem and someone utters "Say. Did we think of changing the batteries..."

What's the deal on "Say."

Comment: [Exclamation: informal North American](https://www.lexico.com/definition/say)

Comment: I'm British and I definitely think of it as American. The British equivalent is [I say](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/i-say).

Comment: Though 'say' or 'I say' sounds a bit meaningless (what exactly are you 'say' ing?), the use of say is used in other languages in a similar way. ['Dis donc' in French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21545/meaning-of-dis-donc), ['sag mal' in German](https://www.dict.cc/german-english/Sag+mal.html). Chinese anyone?

Comment: @KateBunting: surely _I say_ is obsolete?

Comment: @TonyK - Yes, the Macmillan link I supplied calls it 'old-fashioned'.

Comment: Strange thing .. I wonder if this is somewhat .. *Canadian* English ?  I swear I have a friend, Canadian origin, who does this ...

Comment: As pointed out by Mitch, German, too, has this: "Sag, ..." (pl. "Sagt, ...") and I have feeling (but just a feeling) that I've heard this less and less over the years. Perhaps it's something that's slowly been dying out for some reason? Also, might have been introduced into AmE by way of German settlers, which would explain it's absent/less common in BrE? Edit: or perhaps it's more prevalent in sout-western dialects (that's where I'm from) than in eastern ones (that's where I live now). My aunt (Swabian dialect) still uses it quite often in the form of "Sag amoal, ...".

Answer (score 20):

Looking up "*say exclamation/interjection*" on Google, we see that it is definitely American:

> **say** *exclamation*
> <sub>(*North American English, informal*)</sub>
>
> - ​used for showing surprise or pleasure
>   *Say, that's a nice haircut!*
> - used for attracting somebody’s attention or for making a suggestion or comment
>   *Say, how about going to a movie tonight?*
>
> ([Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/say_3))

> **say** *interjection*
> <sub>*chiefly US, informal*</sub>
>
> 1. used to express surprise, shock, etc.
>    *Say, isn't that your friend over there?*
>    *Say, that's a wonderful idea.*
> 2. used to attract the attention of someone
>    *Say there. Can you help me?*
>    *Say, do you want to see a movie tonight?*
>
> ([Learner's Dictionary](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/say))

> 12. EXCLAMATION
>
> **Say** is used to attract someone's attention or to express surprise, pleasure, or admiration.
>
> [*US, informal*]
>
> *Say, how would you like to have dinner one night, just you and me?*
>
> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/say))

And then there's "***I** say*", which is British:

> **I say**
>
> 1. Used preceding an utterance to call attention to it: *I say, do you have the time?*
> 2. Used as an exclamation of surprise, delight, or dismay.
>
> **I say!** *chiefly informal Brit*; an exclamation of surprise.
>
> (The Free Dictionary)

> **I say** (idiom)
> <sub>*British, old-fashioned*</sub>
>
> 1. used to express surprise, shock, etc.
>    *I say! Isn't that your friend over there?*
>    *I say! That's a wonderful idea.*
> 2. used to attract the attention of someone
>    *I say (there). Can you help me?*
>
> ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/I%20say#:%7E:text=British%2C%20old%2Dfashioned,I%20say!))

> **say**
> <sub>*exclamation*; old-fashioned</sub>
>
> used to express surprise or pleasure, or to attract attention to what you are about to say:
>
> - US: *Say, that's really good of you!*
> - US: *Say, how about going out tonight?*
> - UK: ***I** say, what a splendid hat you're wearing!*
>
> ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/say))

> **I say!**
>
> This British exclamation of surprise or astonishment dates back to the late 1700s and may be even older. Although still closely identified with proper Englishmen, its use has in fact **diminished in recent years**, perhaps in part because of its ripeness for parody. It was a favorite interjection of gap-toothed British comedic actor Terry-Thomas, who all but whistled it through his dental cranny.
>
> ([ZOUNDS!: A Browser's Dictionary of Interjections](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=IcLWAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&dq=%22I+say!%22+exclamation+%22surprise%22+%22late%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL9dfj6_H1AhWbsVYBHTpECEAQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22I%20say!%22%20exclamation%20%22surprise%22%20%22late%22&f=false))

From Barrie England's answer to [*What is the origin of the dated British expression "I say!"*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84728/what-is-the-origin-of-the-dated-british-expression-i-say):

> It was much used in comedy acts in the 20th century to introduce a joke, particularly in a double act. For example:
>
> > FUNNY MAN: ‘I say, I say, I say, my wife’s gone to the West Indies.’
> >
> > STRAIGHT MAN: Jamaica?
> >
> > FUNNY MAN: No, she went of her own accord

A common alternative for "*say/I say*" is "*Hey(,)*" in the sense of attracting someone's attention:

> *Hey honey. What would you like for dinner?*
>
> *Hey Ringo. Have you seen...*
>
> *Hey. Did we think of changing the batteries...*

In British English, it's clear that "*I say*" is not in use anymore (see "old-fashioned"). I believe "*say*" (in American English) isn't common either; as opposed to more common calls for attention (such as "Hey", etc.), "*say*" seems to have become old-fashioned as well.

Comment: The only examples of "I say!" that spring to mind are from the lips of Bertie Wooster.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: My thoughts exactly. Nobody uses it any more.

Comment: My father used to use "I say" to attract attention, so I think it must have still been current in the 1950s and 1960s.

Comment: @snakecharmerb There is a 1964 Peter Sellers film called [I say, I say, I say](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2761520/), and I seem to remember that particular combination being a catch phrase at that time, although Google search is flooded with more recent hits for that.

Comment: The "Interjection" def looks like the right one to me. Its basically something one says specifically in conversation (not writing) to test that its OK to proceed with important information. Like [flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control_(data)) in computer networking. You start with "Say..." and if nobody else starts talking at the same time, and the intended listeners seem ready, you proceed delivering the actual sentence.

Comment: Fwiw it sounds old-fashioned to me. If you start a sentence with "Say" I almost expect you to continue with something like "what do you think of that swell malted at the drugstore?"

Comment: I think it would be good to add to your answer (as opposed to the quotes that it's made up of) that "I say" is antiquated. It is definitely ***not*** a feature of modern British English.

Comment: that's great info @snakecharmerb - what region was that ????

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: I thought that was taken care of by the dictionary definitions I cited which mention that "I say" is "old-fashioned". But I've added it anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Fattie UK.  He emigrated from the Irish Free State in the 1940s and worked in the in the National Health Service until the mid-1970s, mostly in the south of England and the East Midlands.  The phrase is absolutely not idiomatic in "Irish" English, so he must have picked it up in England.

Comment: @MissMonicaE I'm only 40, and I'd like to think I have a pretty modern approach to life in general. I listen to modern music, watch modern TV shows, etc. That said, people I associate with regularly still use "say." I'd be tempted to say that this is more of a regional thing than a chronographically correlated thing (at least to some extent). Perhaps here in the Midwest US, we're all old-fashioned and we just don't know it yet.

Answer (score 6):

To my ears, it's very American, the very first thing that comes to mind is [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjwHCeNtTpg) from Terminator 2.

As neither a BrE or an AmE speaker (Irish), I can't say what the British equivalent would be, but "I say" sounds rather more like something an American scriptwriter would write for a stereotyped British character than something a real person would say, but the comment above disagrees. Nevertheless, I feel the more natural thing to do in BrE would be to draw out the first word rather than to use an interjection, e.g. "**Honey**...what would you like for dinner?"

Comment: OUTSTANDING example from a movie, you rock

Comment: "I say ..." is indeed purely comedic these days

Comment: @Fattie I’d point out (American, mostly the Northeast, mid-30’s) that these usages of a leading “say” sound pretty dated and/or stilted—very appropriate to the character in that clip, for instance.

Comment: Yup.  Even to this Brit... I hear the Terminator line and understand that his stilted use of 'Say...' gives away the fact that he's a robot (programmed with outdated hip speak)

Comment: Agree with @Dan - the T1000's use of _correct_ but subtly non-idiomatic speech hints at his true nature.  Also, [Terminators aren't terribly familiar with colloquial speech patterns](https://youtu.be/v23H7c149HM).  (YT clip includes some possibly NSFW languange)

Comment: superb point @AC and Dan ...

Comment: "Honey"? In BE? "Honey" is American English.

Answer (score 4):

In BrE, it's not common to announce new speech with "say" (which sounds distinctly AmE, and like Mark Allen my first thoughts were of Robert Patrick's line in Terminator 2).

But it's certainly common enough regionally to announce a repetition (of something said but not heard) by saying more loudly "I say!" - pronounced like "a-SAY" with the emphasis on the second syllable followed by a short pause - with the previous statement then repeated.

Comment: I think you've summarized the situation Steve ... good one ...

Comment: Now I'm just imagining Foghorn Legcorn - definitely AmE, but only a very specific dialect of deep southern accent.  Possibly also outdated.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, we also have a TV programme in Britain called "Coronation Street", a so-called kitchen-sink drama, and there was a regular character for many years called Fred Elliot who had a very similar verbal schtick to Foghorn Leghorn, with extra "I say, I say"s and unnecessary repetition used for emphasis in an unbroken stream of speech. It didn't sound at all foreign, but it reflected the elements of a very broad regional dialect and particular speaking style.